# Repeater Control does not populate the first data

Tags: c#, asp.net

After binding data to repeater control I am trying to populate some control inside it through Placeholder.

I have written the following .

```
protected void RepeaterDetails_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (Control ri in RepeaterDetails.Items)
        {
            //if (ri.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            //{
                Label lblDatatype = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblDatatype");
                if (lblDatatype.Text != null)
                {
                    if (lblDatatype.Text.ToLower() == "list")
                    {
                        PlaceHolder RepeaterPanel = (PlaceHolder)e.Item.FindControl("RepeaterPanel");
                        DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
                        ddl.Width = 150;
                        RepeaterPanel.Controls.Add(ddl);
                        i++;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        PlaceHolder RepeaterPanel = (PlaceHolder)e.Item.FindControl("RepeaterPanel");
                        tbx = new TextBox();
                        tbx.ID = "TextBox" + i;
                        tbx.Width = 150;
                        RepeaterPanel.Controls.Add(tbx);
                        i++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
           // }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

But the repeater control does not populate the first value.
please see the attached image

[image]

List and textboxes are getting populated except the first one. Can anyone help?

Comment: please provide repeater code

Comment: check lblDatatype.Text null or has some value for first time?

Comment: please find the link for repeater design code...https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5YSXLtZYw73UV9McmQySDNOS2s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have a list of value in  DB.it starts from textbox,List etc.Instead of going to textbox it goes directly to List...

Comment: Can you add the part of the markup containing the Repeater?

Comment: Please find the link.....https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5YSXLtZYw73cmFmdGFSSXN6bDQ/view?usp=sharing